# Array_search malfunctioning?

Tags: php, arrays, search, indexing, return

The first couple of lines is just to double check all variables are as desired. They all give the correct data.

print_r($stack) does give the above stated array element, (+ and more elements)

```
<?php
$item_name = $_POST['item_name']; 
echo $item_name.'<br/><br/>'; // IBM-3246785
print_r($stack);   // Array ( [0] => IBM-3246785 [1] => IBM-3567465 [2] => IBM-4579645 [3] => [4] => IBM-1234567 [5] => [6] => IBM-12345678 [7] => [8] => IBM-24374365 )            

$key = array_search($item_name, $stack);
if ($key !== false) {
    echo "The key where find was found is:" . $key;
} else{
    echo $item_name . " was NOT FOUND in the array";
};
?>
```

Array search returns false EVERYTIME!!! 
Tried replacing $item_name with IBM-3246785 - problem persists.
Can't get it to return the index/key of the selected "item_name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try comparing $item_name and $stack[0], like `if ($item_name == $stack[0]) echo "Done";`
You can try checking for false first, like `if ($key === false) echo "Not"; else echo "Is";`
And maybe You can try different function for retrieving correct array key.

Comment: Tried comparing item_name with stack[0] which gave error.
allthough after trimming array and string, it gave "done".
it still doesn't do the search correctly

Comment: And it got solved. After trimming array and string - it worked!

Answer (score 2):

I just ran this code right here ---

```
<?php

$item_name = "IBM-3246785";
$stack = Array (0 => 'IBM-3246785', 1 => 'IBM-3567465', 2 => 'IBM-4579645', 3 => 'IBM-1234567',4 => 'IBM-12345678', 5 => 'IBM-24374365');


$key = array_search($item_name, $stack);
if ($key !== false) {
    echo "The key where find was found is:" . $key;
} else{
    echo $item_name . " was NOT FOUND in the array";
};
?>
```

and it returned - The key where find was found is:0

Comment: My only guess is that your post variable may have a space in it.. try $item_name = trim($_POST['item_name']);

Comment: indeed, I get the same result. @op: try `var_dump($stack);` instead. It's likely your values contain some whitespace. edit: what @dano says could also be true, you might want to do that, AND apply trim() to your array values, using `$stack = array_map('trim', $stack');`

Comment: And it got solved. After trimming array and string - it worked!